# How to refer to a document in a book?

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct and appropriate when referring to a picture on some page of a book?

> **A:** Look at the picture **on** book page 49.
>
> **B:** Look at the picture **from** book page 49.

Also, would you think the same if a text or an article were involved instead of an iconographic document?

Comment: When referring to a scientific paper, one can say, for instance, "Look at the Figure 2 of that paper".

Comment: Look at the picture **on page 49 of the book**. Look at [x] on page [y] of the book.

Answer (score 1):

> Look at the picture on page 68 of [Spivak, 2006].

Where "Spivak, 2006" refers to an item in your bibliography

Normally you will be using some form of referencing system, such as [Name, year] or numerical referencing.  You can then refer to a particular page of the reference. Put the page number first and then the reference to the book or article.

If you don't have a bibliography, you can achieve a similar result

> Look at page 68 of *Calculus* by Michael Spivak (third edition)

But if you are referring to an image in the current book then only a simple page reference is enough

> Looking at the picture on page 93 we see that ...